# using and try finally, what should I choose

Tags: c#, try-catch, using

I have the following code block;

```
using (var msResp = new MemoryStream(Resp))
{
    try
    {
        Response resp = new Response(msResp);
        SetClientIdentityResponseValue sirv = new SetClientIdentityResponseValue(resp, (int)Response.Properties.Value);
        if (!sirv.IsCredentialsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Authentication failed.");
        }
        if (sirv.IsSubscriptionExpired)
        {
            throw new Exception("Subscription expired.");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        msResp.Close();
    }
}
```

I have read somewhere that a using statement automatically disposes the object.

**Question:**

Is using the Try/Finally combination redundant, when I already use the using statement?

Comment: Yes, it's redundant. Even if you didn't do either, the garbage collector will eventually come around to close the stream, but that's obviously not great to leave it open unnecessarily. Just keep the `using` and ditch `try/finally`

Comment: Why do some programmers use their using statements within a try block?

Comment: @Mobstaa Then the try block is for something else.

Comment: maybe for checking if something went wrong, creating the object?

Comment: @Mobstaa: Some programmers may choose a `try/catch` block with a `using` because they want to handle any errors that are thrown. But in your exact example, there is no need for the `try/finally`

Comment: Thanks! I understand now, that the using statement is just for disposing the object when done, the try/catch/finally, can still be used to catch errors that can be thrown by code within the using statement.

Comment: @Mobstaa Do *not* use code-blocks for highlighting. They're meant for code. Using inappropriate highlighting makes it harder on the eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is redundant.

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.

[using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: @DStanley And the implementation of `Close` is simply to call `Dispose` (technically it's the reverse, but the point is both methods do exactly the same thing).

Comment: I missed that the OP's code called `Close` instead of `Dispose`, but as Servy said, in this case it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the finally. In fact, the using block is implemented internally using a try... finally.

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its redundant. But remember, if you want to catch exception then you need a try-catch. using statement won't catch any exceptions. It just close and disposes the object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling `Close` rather than `Dispose` *It's not blatantly obvious that the code is redundant.*

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422.aspx) for `MemoryStream.Dispose` indicates that the stream is closed when calling `Dispose`:

> This method disposes the stream, by writing any changes to the backing store and closing the stream to release resources.

Which *infers* that `Close` is called.  However, there's *no harm* in explicitly Closing the stream when you're done with it.

Bottom line:  Is it redundant?  Probably.  Is it hurting anthing?  Absolutely not.  I'd prefer to be in the habit of cleaning up after myself, even if a janitor comes in behind me and has nothing to do (or cleans again).

Comment: You shouldn't make it a habit, rather you should be careful. Identify whether a dispose will happen (using statement). If yes, then you don't need to code for the cleanup. It's just doing the task twice.